# Controlling measures uniformly

Tags: measure-theory

Consider $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and restrict ourselves to only measures which are $\mu\ll\mathcal{L}$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is Lebesgue measure. Let $\mu^{n}$ be a sequence of probability measures and $B$ is a set such that $\mathcal{L}(B) = 0$. Is it true that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a compact $K$ such that $\mu^{n}(K)<\epsilon$ for all $n$ where $B\subset K$.

Comment: Is $B$ meant to be relevant? And do you have some requirement like $\mathcal{L}(K)>0$? Otherwise a singleton satisfies this trivially.

Comment: edited...$K\cap B$

Comment: The definition of $\mu \ll \mathcal{L}$ is that $\mu(B)=0$ whenever $\mathcal{L}(B)=0$...

Comment: yes but i want to control the sequence $\mu^{n}(K)$ by a single set $K$

Comment: $K\cap B$ or $K\cup B$? If the former then $\mu(K\cap B) \le \mu(B) = 0$.

Comment: edited again :|

Comment: Question makes more sense now. Without some further conditions on $B$ it is not true - consider $B=[0,1]^2\cap \mathbb{Q}^2$. Then any compact set $K \supset B$ is closed and thus contains $[0,1]^2$; so if any of the measures has $\mu([0,1]^2) > 0$ then $\epsilon=\mu([0,1]^2)$ doesn't work.